# JQuery image viewer with id?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to use [iviewer](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer.html) with image id. Is there possible way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function(){
          var iv1 = $("#viewer").iviewer({
                src: "test_image.jpg", ------> here I would like to put image id. "#image_1"
                update_on_resize: false,
                zoom_animation: false,
                mousewheel: true,
                onMouseMove: function(ev, coords) { },
                onStartDrag: function(ev, coords) { return false; }, //this image will not be dragged
                onDrag: function(ev, coords) { }
          });
    });
</script>

<div id="viewer" class="viewer">
    <img src="test_image.jpg" id="image_1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @Satpal, I try it, it does not work. Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: @Satpal I am sorry. It is ok. It is just duplicated image on div. But, I fixed it using css style `display:none;`

Comment: @Satpal Your suggestion `src: $("#image_1").attr('src')` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
src: $("#viewer").find('img').attr('id') + ".jpg"
```